# Transforming JSON to XML without converting decimal to scientific notation

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, scientific-notation

I am trying to convert `JSON` to `XML` in middle ware tool. I am using `Jackson` libraries to do this transformation. The problem is that for decimal fields (length more than `8`) in `JSON`, the corresponding `XML` value is converted to scientific notation. For example `8765431002.13` is converted to `8.76543100213E8`.

I can convert the scientific notation to normal decimal format if know the name of the field. But in my case, the middleware application will not be aware of field that is coming as decimal.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;


public class JSONDataformat {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              try {
              //String jsonString = "{\"Field1\":18629920.68,\"Field3\":\"test\", \"Field2\":\"null\"}";          
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
              ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
              JsonNode tree = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);

              String jsonAsXml = xmlMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(tree);
              System.out.println(jsonAsXml);
              }
              catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }

       }

}
```

Output

```
<ObjectNode xmlns=""><Field1>1.862992068E7</Field1><Field3>test</Field3><Field2/></ObjectNode>
```

I expected to get `<Field1>` value as `18629920.68` in above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS) feature:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
```

**EDIT**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.Feature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonString = "{\"Field1\": 20121220.00,\"Field3\":\"test\", \"Field2\":\"null\"}";

        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        JsonNode tree = jsonMapper.readTree(jsonString);

        String jsonAsXml = xmlMapper.writer().with(Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN).writeValueAsString(tree);
        System.out.println(jsonAsXml);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<ObjectNode><Field1>20121220</Field1><Field3>test</Field3><Field2>null</Field2></ObjectNode>
```

Comment: Hi Michal, after enabling this feature, I am facing below issue. Numbers having 0 before and after decimal are still getting converted to scientific notation. 20121220.00 still shows in 2.012122E+7 and 
20.00 also shows in 2E+1

Comment: @jkuppal26, in that case try to enable `Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN` feature on `xmlMapper` instance. `Feature` comes from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.Feature` package.

Comment: JsonNode object tree already has the value converted to the scientific notation. So that is not working.

Comment: @jkuppal26, I made a test with `20.00` and it is converted to `20` when `WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN` feature is used.

Comment: could you please send the exact change you made..I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Thank you so much again Michal!